# Email notification on ContentVersion object

Tags: apex, email, email-template, email-alert, contentversion

I am sending an email notification if a field is changed on Content Version object through Apex as we cannot create Workflows/processbuilder on Contentversion object. In my Apex code, I am referring to a email template which I created for this purpose.  In the body of email template, I am trying to include few ContentVersion fields, but there is no option to select merge fields for Content Version object.

Is there a way I can use ContentVersion fields in my email template ?

Comment: an option: use a VF email template that can use custom component(s) that can fetch fields from CV

Comment: Another more complicated option is to build your own merge fields. Pick a syntax like <<!fieldName>> and then you can merge them yourself in your apex code.